# Adding tabs to all documents in Docusign

Tags: docusignapi

I have a requirement to first create the Docusign envelope in create status and later attach a list of documents and send it out.For this purpose I am first creating envelope with Envelope Rest API,adding documents using the Documents Rest API and finally sending it out.The anchor tabs that I initially added during create do not get picked up on the attached documents.It seems to ignore those tabs.Is there a way to add anchor tabs to get picked up on all documents.
Thanks
Lakshmi

Answer (score 1):

One thing I would suggest checking is the anchor tabs scope - document or envelope. This is something that many people don't know about.
https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/tabs/auto-place/
"anchor population scope"

Also, are you using a composite template by any chance? that may matter

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say what the issue is without seeing your request. As your use case is complex and there are many variables, I'd advise opening a support case so we can have a look in detail